# Avoid Space from comma separated Ip address in Regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am able to get comma separated ip address but unable to avoid spaces, what should i change here...

```
/^\*$|^(?:\d|1?\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:\d|1?\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){3}(?:\s*,\s*(?:\d|1?\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:\d|1?\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){3})*$/
```

Comment: What is your string?

Comment: See [your regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JpP4ol/3) against some strings. Which of them should be matched and which shouldn't?

Comment: Then you should remove `\s` metacharacters.

Comment: See this example: http://www.regextester.com/22

Comment: So can you provide me new String ? @revo

Comment: @Mohammad  here is my Ip    11.22.44.5,22.44.55.88  but it shouldn't work when i put space after comma...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put your pattern in Regex101, you will see the regex explanation. So, for your pattern you will find this:

> \s* matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])

So, you have just to remove the `\s*` in your pattern and you are set:

```
/^\*$|^(?:\d|1?\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:\d|1?\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){3}(?:\s*,\s*(?:\d|1?\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])(?:\.(?:\d|1?\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){3})*$/
                                                                      Here -----^---^
```

**[working demo](https://regex101.com/r/2fKqiP/2)**

If you check at the new regex diagram, you can see that there is no spaces allowed:

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/WaeEMoRz2S4SrPFa)

Comment: Not working-- it is able to contain Space before comma.. http://www.regextester.com/22  (11.44.55.2 ,44.55.22.6) i wants like (11.44.55.2,44.55.22.6) this

Comment: @PinalKalal, check the link I put in the answer. It's working on regex101. If you find a pattern that it isn't update the link and send it over

Comment: @PinalKalal, btw I tested your like and didn't see any problem, the matching ip has no spaces.

Comment: @PinalKalal, great. Glad to help